# Jave HttpClient - JSON content not parsing -

Tags: java, http, get, httpclient

I'm working on trying to figure out Gson. I have the GET request connecting, and I'm getting a 200, but the JSON body seems to be empty - it's fine when I can from elsewhere, I do see the JSON in the content.

Partners is just a class of Strings to match the Partner object, where PartnersArray is just an ArrayList of those Partners to match the JSON structure.

```
public HttpResponse<String> getRequest(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        
        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) HttpRequest.newBuilder().
                uri(URI.create(url)).
                header("accept", "application/json").
                build();
        System.out.println("Request Header : " + request.headers());
        
        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        
        PartnersArray partners = new Gson().fromJson(response.body(), PartnersArray.class);
        
        if (response.statusCode() == 200)
        {
            System.out.println("HttpStatus Good");
            System.out.println(partners.toString());
        }
        
        return response;
        
    }
```

Comment: Looks like I am getting the response, so clearly something wrong with my mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually that happens when the json structure doesn't match the class structure. Maybe you can add here the json you are getting in the response and both PartnersArray and Partner classes.

Comment: That’s exactly what it was. I got it resolved. I didn’t see that the top level was an array and as soon as I created a class to wrap the main object, it was good. Thanks for the reply!